# Size check of form input before saving to database

Tags: java, html, mysql, validation

I have created an html form where input is going to be inserted into a database(mysql). Before I start inserting the data I perform some serverside form validation in java. I would like to make sure during this validation that the data is not to big for their respective fields.

I am unsure of how to do this though.

These are the fields with datatypes that will be saved in the db:

- List, item
- ID, smallint(5)
- AID, mediumint(5)
- Pro, varchar(45)
- Lot, varchar(45)
- Temp, smallint
- Comment, text

The only idea I have so far is to make a check like:

```
if(inputSize > maxsize)
```

But I'm unsure of what to choose for inputSize or maxsize. For the varchar I guess I could simply choose the number of characters given in the definition (45 that is) and compare it to the length of the strings. But I'm unsure of how to handle the integers.

Any suggestions? Either on how to handle the integers or if there is a better way to do the serverside size validation.

Answer (score 0):

//for varchar i guess but following code is C# check syntax for java :)

```
if(str.Length > 45)
{
    str = str.Substring(0,45)
}
```

// integers i guess

```
 public static boolean checkIntegerRange(int num, int min, int max)
 {
       return num > min && num < max;    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Integer, you can check if it out of range. Here is a link(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html) where the range of integer is explained.

Answer (score 0):

For varchar values, you can validate with  the length specified (45 in your case), you can also add the *maxlength* attribute to your *input* fields, which would prevent users from typing too many characters.

For numeric values, I would refer to MySQL documentation to get the maximum values that can be handled by each type:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html